# Meaning of val / var when using Kotlin Primary constructor

Tags: kotlin

I have seen Kotlin-examples using a Primary-constructor like this:

```
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) {}
```

And I have seen example with the var or val keyword, like this:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {}
```

**What the difference? When do I have to use which variation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors), with `var` or `val` in the constructor you create a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#properties-and-fields) in the class. If you do not write it, then it is only a [parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#parameters) that is passed to the constructor. As an example:

```kotlin
class Person(val firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    
    // firstName and lastName accessible
  
    fun getFirstName() = firstName // firstName accessible

    fun getLastName() = lastName // lastName not accessible
}
```

So if you want to continue to use the `firstName` and `lastName`, I would make a property out of it.